# Unable to click on link using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Tried using `xpath`,`css`,`id`, `href`, partial text,`link` text nothing is working
Is returning no text exists on the page

wanna click on Quality Center

how to click please help me out

Below is the html code what i tried:-

```
<document>
<html>
   <head>
   <body class="Nav">
      <a id="Cahill_Line" href="Cahill Line" onclick="highlight('Cahill_Line')" target="" title="</a><HR>"/>
         <hr/>
         <br/>
      <a id="Help" href="javascript:LoadPage('3001', 'https://wiki.ucern.com/display/ipfactory/Revision%2bInfo%2bHelp'); void(0);" onclick="highlight('Help')" target="" title="Help"> Help</a>
      <br/>
      <a id="Processing_Info" href="javascript:toggle('divProcessing_Info', 'Processing_Info','WebHelp/processing_info.htm');" title="Build Processing">Build Processing</a>
      <br/>
      <div id="divProcessing_Info" class="indent" style="DISPLAY: none;">
      <a id="FT_Reports" href="javascript:toggle('divFT_Reports', 'FT_Reports','WebHelp/feature_tracker_reports.htm');" title="Feature Tracker">Feature Tracker</a>
      <br/>
      <div id="divFT_Reports" class="indent" style="DISPLAY: none;">
      <a id="Maven2" href="javascript:toggle('divMaven2', 'Maven2','webhelp/maven2_reports.htm');" title="Maven2">Maven2</a>
      <br/>
      <div id="divMaven2" class="indent" style="DISPLAY: none;">
      <a id="Navigator" href="javascript:toggle('divNavigator', 'Navigator','webhelp/navigator_reports.htm');" title="Navigator">Navigator</a>
      <br/>
      <div id="divNavigator" class="indent" style="DISPLAY: none;">
      <a id="Pkg_Reports" href="javascript:toggle('divPkg_Reports', 'Pkg_Reports','WebHelp/package_reports.htm');" title="Package">Package</a>
      <br/>
      <div id="divPkg_Reports" class="indent" style="DISPLAY: none;">
      <a id="CertStatusRpt" href="javascript:toggle('divCertStatusRpt', 'CertStatusRpt','WebHelp/cert_status_reports.htm');" title="Quality Center" style="font-weight: normal;">Quality Center</a>
```

Comment: Please gothrough https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that people can help you. Please share the code you have tried/html of webpage or url if its public site , so that other can understand the issue & help

Comment: If you put HTML in your question you need to format it as code (select it and press control+k), otherwise it won't show up on the question.

Comment: Am new to stackoverflow,excuse me if i didnt follow proper rules to ask the question,next will maintain.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could do like this:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("CertStatusRpt")));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("CertStatusRpt")).Click();
```